# Continuous listening new emails in spring boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, smtp, jakarta-mail, pop3

How can I read new emails using the spring boot app?
by which library it can be possible.?

going through many tutorials but didn't get any appropriate answers till now.

I want to build an application that will continuously read the mailbox, it will read only new emails coming to the outlook server inbox periodically.

the emails also contain the audio attachment which I want to download and store on the server.

is there any way to listen to every new email from the inbox, and once it's done mark it as read? so same mails can not be retrieved again for reading.

anyone, please help me to build a sample program.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Spring Integration supports this out-of-the-box. Just wire that up.

Comment: ok sir, will try this. Thanks. @M.Deinum

Answer (score 0):

To read/listen new emails in real time you can use IMAP protocol, JavaMail API and IMAP IDLE feature.

On higher-level refer the following steps:

1. Establish an IMAP connection with the email server using JavaMail API
2. Monitor the Inbox with IMAP IDLE. (IMAP IDLE allows our application to receive immediate notification when new message arrives in mailbox)

For more detailed implementation refer this article: https://medium.com/@sushant7/how-to-monitor-incoming-emails-in-a-spring-boot-application-indefinitely-7dabbdb74b2d